# Is there a way to conditionally disable the swipe to go back gesture in react native iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-navigation

I'm looking for a way to conditionally disable the swipe to go back gesture in react native iOS. I'm using the `react-navigation` library to control navigation. For Android, I am able to do it using BackHandler. Is it possible to do something similar in iOS?

```
  componentDidMount() {
      BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", this.handleBackButton);
  }

  handleBackButton = () => {
    if (this.props.creating) {
      return true; // Disables the back button in Android
    }
  };

  componentWillUnmount() {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener(
        "hardwareBackPress",
        this.handleBackButton
      );
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is an option to disable gestures:

```
screen: ExampleView
    navigationOptions: {
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    },
```

Check for more details here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1063

Comment: This will disable gestures for the screen completely. But I'm trying to only disable gestures when `this.props.creating` is true.

Comment: if you rely on `prop` I'd assume that it comes from upper scope. It's possible to disable conditionally swipe back on `Navigator/Screen` level

Answer (score 0):

> But I'm trying to only disable gestures when this.props.creating is
>   true.

Try adding this static method to your component.

```
   static navigationOptions = props => {
      return {
        gesturesEnabled: this.props.creating ? false : true
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

[StackNavigator takes navigationOptions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#StackNavigatorConfig) representing the "Default navigation options to use for screens"

Example:

```
 const RootStackNavigator = StackNavigator(
  {
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen
    },
    Main: {
      screen: MainScreen
    }
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Login',
    navigationOptions: {
      gesturesEnabled: false   // <- add this line
    }
  }
);
```